# Why do links from tags that don't exist take me to the "featured" tab which then incorrectly says there are no bountied questions?

Tags: support, tags, search, bounties, bountied-tab

Someone was proposing an edit which would have created a new tag. While looking at the edit, I clicked on the link for the new tag. Normally, this should show me something like this:

---

[image]

---

**However, on Travel SE, it shows me this:**

---

[image]

---

It doesn't only happen if I click a tag link. It also happens if I [search for [gibberish]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gibberish) or any tag that doesn't exist. I'm taken to the same "Featured tab".

Why does this happen?

Also, why does the page say that there are no active bounties, when there are in fact [seven questions with active bounties](https://travel.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) at the moment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sorting options in question lists (i.e */questions), which the tag page you're talking about is a part of (the URL is */questions/tagged/), persist between views.

If you change it from "Featured" to something else, say "Votes", then close the page and open it again, it will be on the "Votes" tab.

As far as I know it persists only per-site and only for question lists that have */questions/* in the URL. It doesn't, for example, affect the home page.

---

As for why the notice says there are no active bounties—there are no active bounties in the scope of that tab, so the message is correct, although maybe a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Oh... Yeah, I see. I feel a bit silly now :)

Comment: No reason to feel silly, it's not even obvious that the tag and question pages are the same without looking at the url